# Dynamic Form Save into DB

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello guys hope you can help me and gimme some advice cause i don't know what to do right now. Please kindly help.

I've dynamic form where i can add (append) new row but when i tried to save it's value it said undefined offset. Please look into my code

This is my View

```
<tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="analisa[0]" placeholder="Analisa Penyebab" style="resize: none;
                height: 50px"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="tindakan[0]" placeholder="Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan" 
                style="resize: none; height: 50px"></textarea></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pic[0]" placeholder="PIC"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="tanggal_pelaksanaan[0]"</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <a class="button" href="#" role="button" id="add">&nbspTambah Analisa</a>
```

And this is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;

    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#tbanalisa tbody').append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa"+i+"\" placeholder=\"Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"tindakan"+i+"\" placeholder=\"Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan\"style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pic"+i+"\" placeholder=\"PIC\"></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"date\" name=\"tanggal_pelaksanaan"+i+"\" id=\"date"+i+"\" ></td>"+"</tr>");

    document.getElementById('count').value = i;  
    });

});
```

And this is my function in Controller

```
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
        $data[] = array(
            'id_tindakan'=>$tindakan->id,
            'analisa'=>$request->analisa[$i],
            'tindakan'=>$request->tindakan[$i],
            'pic'=>$request->pic[$i],
            'tanggal_pelaksanaan'=>$request->tanggal_pelaksanaan[$i]
        );
    }
    DB::table('analisas')->insert($data);
```

I Tried to change index of each array in javascript
not analisa[i] but i try analsia[1] and it works fine. Why i make my code error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined offset` means either there is nothing at that index or simply your object is not array. For your case, I think your variable is not an array. In your Javascript, you do

```
name=\"analisa"+i+"\"
```

Which means the actual name is rendered in html as

```
name="analisa2"
```

Whereas in Laravel you want to get it with `analisa[2]`, which is not an array.

As a solution, you either change your Javascript to name it as an array

```
name=\"analisa["+i+"]\"
```

Or change your controller to pick the exact same name sent from Javascript

```
'analisa'=>$request->analisa.$i,
```